Extract flow direction/flow arrow/velocity vector from HEC-RAS
When it comes to flood simulation, knowing the direction of flow is very important. However, HEC-RAS's RasMapper only give the absolute value of velocity. It can only show the arrow on its board (as shown in Figure) but the arrow can not be saved to a file(e.g., tif). How can I extract the flow direction? For example, saving the velocity on x-direction and y-direction respectively.
enter image description here
extract the flow direction

Export the output tables. https://www.hec.usace.army.mil/confluence/rasdocs/rasum/6.5/viewing-results/tabular-output/detailed-output-tables - you probably need "Flow Distribution In Cross Sections" or the like for velocity vectors. You can also look at the export facilities: https://www.hec.usace.army.mil/confluence/rasdocs/rasum/6.5/hec-ras-data-exchange

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
